# Why does shared_ptr not delete its memory?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

```
int main(){

    int* iptr;
    {
    std::shared_ptr<int> sptr = std::make_shared<int>(12);
    iptr = sptr.get();
    }

    std::cout << *iptr;

    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
12
```

I was expecting that the content to which **iptr** points, would have been deleted, at the end of inner curly braces. But output shows 12. Do I miss something?

Comment: *"was expecting that the content to which iptr points, would have been deleted"* They were deleted. Accessing a deleted object causes undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including this. More practically speaking, deleting an object from the heap makes the memory it has occupied available for reuse. The memory itself is still there though, and isn't zeroed (because there's no reason to do so), and might not be reused *immediately*.

Comment: Don't expect when you free an object that accessing its location will lead to a crash or that it's contents will be changed by the deletion. It is undefined behavior to look at such memory. Anything can happen. In practice `c++` has a you don't pay for what you don't need principle. This means that `c++` won't waste cycles filling deleted memory with 0 or random garbage because it does not matter, It is UB to use such a pointer and look at the memory that was deleted. Any program that looks at such memory is considered malformed and broken by the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does shared_ptr not delete its memory?

shared_ptr **does** delete the memory that it owns when it is the last owner.

> I was expecting that the content to which iptr points, would have been deleted, at the end of inner curly braces.

You were expecting correctly.

> But output shows 12. Do I miss something?

You're missing that accessing through invalid pointers results in **undefined behaviour**.

Answer (score 5):

As properly pointed by eerorika, you are seeing undefined behavior here. Particularly, a *dangling pointer*. I.e. a pointer that points to a location with a deleted memory. Not only you can get arbitrary results, but your program might behave in a completely unexpected way.

I would strongly recommend using sanitizers to avoid such problems. Here is the output of the code compiled with `-fsanitize=address` (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Po3r9cvq7):

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000020 at pc 0x000000401439 bp 0x7fff630ed360 sp 0x7fff630ed358
READ of size 4 at 0x603000000020 thread T0
    #0 0x401438 in main /app/example.cpp:12
    #1 0x7fdd09b5b0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
    #2 0x40121d in _start (/app/output.s+0x40121d)
```

As you can see, it points out that you are trying to access a deleted memory. It also provides call stacks for operations that allocated and released the memory, which is very handy.